# Unable to reset WAS admin password. unable to login WAS console

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am unable to login inot WAS Admin console. So I am trying to reset the admin credential after disabling security(security.xml-enabled="false"), but unable to save the new password. Any idea what should I check and troubleshoot?

I tried entering the credentials on soap.clients.props, but no help. WAS version : 7.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ejs.resources.security.html?cp=SS7JFU_7.0.0%2F1-15-7-225

SECJ7342E: Failed to validate user/password 
**Explanation   Failed to validate user password in WIM registry**
Action  None

The credentials that you entered do they exist in the WIM registry?

From the screen shot it appears that you are using the File Based registry. Check that the ID and passwords match the values in that File Registry.

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue. I was trying to use the old password again.

Answer (score 1):

If you disabled security, then restart your server, so it starts plain, unsecured and enable security again via console. There will be prompt to specify admin user and password (I'm assuming you are using default Federated repository with file based). Provide new password there and restart the server.

In the page you are showing now, leave Server user identity as default - Automatically generated. This is not page, where you change user password.

Settings in `soap.clients.props` are not related to password changing. Once you set new password via console, you can update that file, so you won't be prompted, when you stop server from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This technote is also helpful when forgetting your WAS Admin console password:

Forgot password and cannot access WebSphere Application Server administrative console
https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302